# How can I get all my data in a single table, rather than split across multiple tables?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now, after my user has typed into 3 textfields, I get 3 cells that each contain one of the values type by the user.

How can I make it so the 3 values will all be displayed in the same cell?

In my `NavnCell` file, I have created multiple labels, but they still act the same. Its seems like my app takes the first value in the array and displays it and then creates another cell to display the second value.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

 class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var files: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
func mini() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BilletSalg")
    let usersRef =   ref.child("tickets").childByAutoId().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        self.files.append(snapshot)

        print(snapshot)


})
}

   let cellNavn = "cellNavn"

  var holes: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []


  let CoursesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BilletSalg")





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CoursesRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in



        self.holes = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("tickets").children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
        var newItems = [FIRDataSnapshot]()

        for item in snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("tickets").children {
            newItems.append(item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        }

        //replace the old array
         self.holes = newItems

    self.tableView.reloadData()


    })

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel",  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    tableView.registerClass(NavnCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellNavn)




}


func handleCancel() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return holes.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellNavn,  forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NavnCell




   // I want 3 labels to display the 3 values typed by the user, so in each Row you can view the 3 values
    cell.timeLabel.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String



    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.holes[indexPath.item].value as? String


   //        cell.textLabel?.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String
   //
   //        cell.anotherlabel.text? = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String


    return cell

    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}





}
```

Comment: "cell.timeLabel.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String" — but that's just one label (cell.timeLabel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return holes.count
}
```

I think here you want to have something like holes.count / 3 because you want to show three values in one cell, so your number of rows should be like holes div 3, right?

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath it should be something like that:

```
let newIndex = indexPath.row * 3
cell.timeLabel.text = self.holes[newIndex].value as? String
cell.timeLabel2.text = self.holes[newIndex + 1].value as? String //next value
cell.timeLabel3.text = self.holes[newIndex + 2].value as? String//another next value
```

but honestly it'd be much simpler for you to prepare your data the right way from the beginning. something like newHoles where newHole consists of self.hole1, self.hole2 and self.hole3.

Comment: thank you for the solution, it works! 

However I'm not sure I actually understand the theory behind this. 

I understand newIndex + 1, but why the indexPath.row * 3. (why multiply it by 3?

And div holes.count by 3, does it create 3 columns or something like that in the row? or what does it exactly do?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: tableView.datasource is quite simple (or, if you want, dumb). it shows your data as it is. so, we need to update your data before tableview will show it.
for example, your data has 9 values, and you want to show 3 cells with 3 values in each.

1. first we need to tell tableView that your data has only 3 cells (rows). for this we are dividing 9 by 3.

Comment: 2. second, we need to tell tableView that it should show 3 consecutive values in each cell. 
if your indexPath.row == 0 (it's your first cell), we need to show values #0, #1, #2. so, we are using newIndex, newIndex + 1, and newIndex + 2.

after that we have to show the next sequence of values in the next cell(indexPath.row = 1), but our first value should be #3 (because #0, #1, #2 were shown in the first cell). to get the number of our next value we have to multiply indexPath.row (1) by 3. 

with indexPath.row = 2 we will get values #6, 7, 8 and so on.